# JQuery text() is not working in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery

I developed a simple webapp using asp.net, C# and jquery and I'm testing my app using Internet Explorer 7. I used ajax to retrieve data from the server. But calling the text() of jquery is not working, instead it will call the val() method, for example I created a drop down list called NameDrp, then,

```
$("SELECT#NameDrp option:selected").text()
```

The above call will give the value not the text.

EDIT: markup of the select

```
<select id="NameDrp" name="NameDrp">
   <option value="1">Monkey</option>
   <option value="2">Lion</option>
   <option value="3">Tiger</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup of your `<select>` element?

Answer (score 2):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qHsL8/1/)

```
$("select#NameDrp").change(function() {
    var text = $("select#NameDrp option:selected").html();
    $('#test').html(text);
});
```

you can use `.text()` or even `.html()`

### [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/qHsL8/3/)

```
var arrTxt = [];
$("#NameDrp :selected").each(function(i, selected){
  arrTxt[i] = $(selected).text();
});


  $('#get_val').click(function(){
    alert( 'Value: ' + $('#NameDrp').val() );
  });
  $('#get_text').click(function(){
    alert( 'Text: ' + $('#NameDrp :selected').text() );
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. But even if using the .html(), its not working on my side. I'm using jquery 1.5.1. But I doubt that's the issue. It keeps getting the value of the option not the text. Actually I'm calling the $("select#NameDrp option:selected").text() inside of the $.ajax()..